# Display json file in Browser using Node.JS without file extension

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have made a server using javascript and Node.js that shows a JSON file in my browser.

However, I would like to call the site `http://localhost:8888/Test.json` without an extension.
For example just: `http://localhost:8888/Test`

Here is my server code:

```
var     http = require("http"),
        url = require("url"),
        path = require("path"),
        fs = require("fs")
        port = process.argv[2] || 8888;
        file = (__dirname + '/Test.json');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  var uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname, filename = path.join(process.cwd(), uri);

  var contentTypesByExtension = {
    '.html': "text/html",
    '.css':  "text/css",
    '.js':   "text/javascript",
    '.json': "application/json" //Edited due to answer - Still no success :(
  };

  path.exists(filename, function(exists) {

    if(!exists) {
      res.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      res.write("404 Not Found\n");
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, file) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error: ' + err);
            return;
        }

        file = JSON.parse(file);
        console.dir(file);

        var headers = {};
        var contentType = contentTypesByExtension[path.extname(file)];
        if (contentType) headers["Content-Type"] = contentType;
        res.writeHead(200, headers);
        res.write(JSON.stringify(file, 0 ,3));
        res.write
        res.end();
        });    

  });

}).listen(parseInt(port, 10));

console.log("JSON parsing rest server running at\n  => http://localhost:" + 
port + "/\nPress CTRL + C to exit and leave");
```

How can I do that?
Should I use routes/express?
Does someone have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Cheers, Vlad

Comment: I see the contentType work you have in there, is your intent to return the file based on the request's accept content-type (because they often send more than one)?  Or do you want to always default to some file extension?

Comment: My intension was to create a restful server with node.js, that simply displays a json file formatted in json-format in my browser. I want to do a specific request too, for example for ID's of the json file: "localhost:8888/Test/1"; ---> This only should show the position of 1 based on the ID of the json-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just used the sledgehammer method now with commenting this code fragment out:

```
if(!exists) {
      res.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      res.write("404 Not Found\n");
      res.end();
      return;
    }
```

Now it works to call just: `http://localhost:8888/Test`

Cheers, Vlad

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably due to the content type. Having the extension .json is probably triggering your browser to consume it as `application/json`. So if you remove the extension you need to add the proper `Content-Type`.

Given that you are already playing around with content types, can't you just add it here, and make sure you write the type for jsons as well?

```
  var contentTypesByExtension = {
    '.html': "text/html",
    '.css':  "text/css",
    '.js':   "text/javascript",
    '.json': "application/json" // <---
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I already have tried that, but it still does not work. I just let it included now. Maybe it has something to do with the path declaration. I'm quite new to node.js, that's why I'm still struggling with this problem.